# $(...).datetimepicker is not a function when use converse.js

Tags: xmpp, conflict, converse.js

I want to implement XMPP chat functionality in my system using `converse.js` for client side chat interface. but when i use `converse.js` in my layout page, browser showing me error like

```
$(...).datetimepicker is not a function
$(...).dataTable is not a function.
```

I have used bootstrap datetimepicker and datatables. It seems like jquery conflictions. 
I have tried to resolve conflictions by changing place of some jquery files. but i didn't get success. So how can i remove conflictions?

Comment: what conflicts, can you with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: As of version 3.0.1 this shouldn't be an issue anymore. In previous builds the `$.noConflict` call wasn't being made. This is now fixed in 3.0.1. If you're using an older version, then the text below is still relevant.**

Converse.js comes bundled with jQuery. It uses jQuery's [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) method to relinquish control of the $ variable and therefore to avoid conflicts with other versions of jQuery, but apparently this doesn't always work reliably.

There are a few things you can try:

- Load converse.js before all your other JS libraries.
- Alternatively, drop your own jQuery and instead use the one included in converse.js. You can access it via `converse.env.jQuery`.
- Or alternatively use the converse.js bundle that doesn't include jQuery: https://cdn.conversejs.org/dist/converse-no-jquery.min.js